# How to scale single node Kafka to multiple node cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera-cdh

I am going to install Kafka for company messaging. The plan is to first install the Kafka on a single huge machine and scale it to 4-5 machines (a cluster) later if needed.

I have little experience about Kafka. I want to ask whether it is possible to scale by just changing the parameter in broker configuration and install Zookeeper on newly joined machine.

Or how can I roughly do this in the easiest way? More specifically Cloudera Kafka in CDH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To scale Kafka you will have to add more partitions to topics if needed to using kafka-topics.sh. And than reassign partitions to your new brokers using kafka-reassign-partitions.sh.

The reassign utility will replicate and dispatch your data automatically. You can do it for a whole topic or for a selective set of partitions.

The complete documentation is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools). Just take a look at section 6.

Comment: thanks for your response. very helpful. one confusing still, do I have to install kafka package kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz on every new machine in the cluster and start zk and kafka server on them to make them integrating into old running kafka system? thanks again

Comment: If you want to scale out, it is recommended to have a ZK ensemble separated from your Kafka cluster. Basically, as you said, you will have to install kafka package everywhere and point them to the same ZK ensemble. It's thanks to ZK that all kafka brokers will know that they are in a cluster.